# How to indentify which data is selected by user in selectbox (data is union of two tables)?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a need of display two diff. tables's data in one selectbox. so i use following query:

```
<select name="account[]" id="account" class="input" multiple size="3">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php
        global $mysqli;
        $query  = "SELECT `number` as num, `id` from `table1` where `account_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' UNION ALL SELECT `number` as num, `id` from `table2` where `account_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."'";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
        while($row5 = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row5['id'];?>"><?php echo $row5['num'];?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

so all data are fetch according to my need. But now i have a problem.

> When i inserted user selected data, how to indentify that  user selected data is from table1 or table2 ?

I have a some ideas:
(1) Create two diff. queries in selectbox and bind predifined value.
exa.:

```
<option value="table1.9999"><?php echo $row5['num'];?></option>
<option value="table2.2222"><?php echo $row5['num'];?></option>
```

(2) insert table2's id(here id is automatic inserted id primary key) maually.

> like:  id=10000
>   so i check that if id>10000 then it is from table2.

But the upper things is like petch. so what is the alternavites for do upper things.
Any ideas are welcome.Thanks in advance.

**SIDE NOTE:** table structure is good according to my need. so i cannot change whole table structure. But i can add fields in tables.

Comment: **Please** separate HTML from SQL. Either in your code and questions. These have absolutely nothing to do with each other.

Comment: right,but i posted this beacause i am try to explain my quetion and try to explain my need.

Comment: Is the combination of number and id unique for both tables?
If not you will not get araound one of the ideas you have.

Comment: ya.. numbers are unique on both tables but the id is autoincrement so it may be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a column to your SELECT statement, that specifies whether the data comes from table1 or table2:

```
SELECT `number` as num, `id`, "Table1" as source 
from `table1` 
where ... 
UNION ALL 
SELECT `number` as num, `id`, "Table2" as source 
from `table2` 
where ...
```

Then you can use this `source` column to determine if the record is from Table1 or Table2.

If you need a unique identifier across both tables, just concatenate the id with the table number. Something like this should work:

```
SELECT `number` as num, `id` & "-Table1" as uniqueid 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you separated this functionalities, so now you have a php backend with delivers the query result as a json string

optionlist.php

```
    global $mysqli;
    $optionlist=array();
    $query  = "SELECT `number` as num, `id`, 'Table1' as source  
               from `table1` 
               where `account_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."' 
               UNION ALL 
               SELECT `number` as num, `id`, 'Table2' as source 
               from `table2` 
               where `account_id`='".$_SESSION['account_id']."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error);
    while($row5 = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $optionlist[] = $row5;
    }
    echo json_encode($optionlist);
```

now in your mainfile you have an empty select box and a js to fill it up

main.html

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery.ajax({ url: 'optionlist.php'
              dataType: 'json';
           }).done(function(jsonlist) {
              for(var i=0;i<jsonlist.length;i++) {
                   theoption=jsonlist[i];
                   jQuery('#account').append('<option rel="'+ theoption.source +" value="'+theoption.id+'">'+ theoption.num '</option>';
              }

           });
</script>
<select name="account[]" id="account" class="input" multiple size="3">
    <option value="">Select</option>
</select>
```